# Optimal solution for managing tens of thousands users of a desktop app accessing a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, database-connection, roles

I would like to develop a specific app that can be used to access a database developed in PostgreSQL. The app performs calculations and asks for the required data from the database server.

The user can download the app from a website if he has registered. After starting the app, the user has to log in to be able to use it.
Now the question:
What would be the most sensible solution in this example?
To be honest, I don't want to create a separate role for each user.
My idea is that the app only accesses the database via a general role, for example with the name "usership". With this role, a user only has well-defined read access. It is possible that users should also be able to save their own settings or measured values ​​under their user name in certain tables. Access would then only be possible with the correct user name and password, which are specified with each operation on the relevant tables (however, this effort would not be necessary for read-only access to other tables with general data).

The question is whether there are any limits to how many apps can communicate with the database at the same time via the same database credentials / username "usership".

I don't want to have to create a separate DB role for each customer. Somehow that doesn't seem right to me, if only because adding new employees or deleting them means major interventions in the database schema (create / drop role). Basically, the app should do nothing else than a website where several users are logged in at the same time, the only difference being that the app does not run in the browser and everything works either on the client side at the application level or on the database server.

Comment: I'm confused. You say each "how many apps can communicate with the database at the same time via the same database connection" - but each desktop app would need a different connection. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Also are you expecting tens of thousands of concurrent users?

Comment: I mean with the same connection: database user (role)  + password + host + db name
and yes, but for the beginning just hundreds to thousands app users.

Comment: That is not a database connection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_connection). You mean the same credentials or maybe "connection string"

Comment: How many concurrent users / concurrent connections do you need to support?

Comment: yes. basically the thing that I have to do at the application level (e.g. with python connector): connection = psycopg2.connect(
 host="localhost",
 database="whatever",
 user="usership",
 password="blabla87332"
)

Comment: At the beginning, of course, I only expect 100 to 1000 users. it should be easily scalable if necessary. I mean, a website actually has "any" number of logged in users (depending on how much storage space and performance the server provides).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any limits on sharing of usernames + passwords in postgres. You can have hundreds or thousands of concurrent connections using the same username + password.

There *can be* issues with many hundreds or thousands of concurrent connections, depending on your database hardware, especially ram.

While Postgres supports thousands of concurrent connections in theory, in practice I've run into memory issues as the # of open connections increases. If this is a problem and a large % of your connections are idle at any one moment, you can add a layer of connection pooling with something like [pgbouncer](https://pgdash.io/blog/pgbouncer-connection-pool.html), but keep in mind that adds another process to monitor.

In general, however, I wouldn't recommend this approach. You'd be providing direct, essentially anonymous access to your shared database. I expect it would be difficult to secure your database credentials in the client, and with direct access it should be fairly easy to construct SQL queries that would take down your database server. This would be difficult to monitor or prevent against since all users would be the same and you'd have no way to revoke access in case of abuse (without changing the password for everyone that has access).

From a security standpoint I'd definitely recommend being able to identify your users, monitor their usage separately and revoke access individually. I don't know of any performance issues with having many thousands of separate postgres users/credentials.

-- Scalability --

Using a postgres cluster with read replicas and load balancing (e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/requests-rds-read-replicas/) you should be able to scale this horizontally fairly easily if the need arises.